# Unable to run react app on IE browser - Giving const assignment error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and creating a react app using the CDN files. The app works fine in other brwoser except IE11.

I am getting below error.

[image]

These are my CDN files -

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.13.15/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- babel is required in order to parse JSX -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Also, I have searched and found we should import polyfill in our app. but since I am using the web version of react I do not have a way to import. I have tried to include this file at the top https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js but it didn't work. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you created `babel.config.json` file?? and why not using `create-react-app`?

Comment: since i am using the web version of babel there is no option to create babel.config @techipank